# How to add tab page in Devexpress TabControl on button click?

Tags: asp.net, button, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a **Devexpress Tabcontrol**. 
Inside that Tabcontrol I am having **Devexpress Grid**.
Inside that Grid I am loading **button** on run-time by following code.

```
GridViewCommandColumn col = new GridViewCommandColumn();
GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton CusButton = new GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton();
CusButton.ID = "btn1";
CusButton.Image.Url = "~/Images/color.jpg";    
col.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
col.CustomButtons.Add(CusButton);
gridview.Columns.Add(col);
```

Now on that **button click**, I need to add a Tab page in that Devexpress Tabcontrol retaining this Grid on first tab.

But its not getting added, its getting refreshed on that button click

I just created an object for **Tab page** and loaded **Gridcontrol.ascx** user control which has devexpress gridview.
After that I just called **addTabPages** method in my **Tabpage usercontrol** and passed this **Tabpage** object as a parameter in it.In below code **tabPreview** is the object for **Tabcontrol usercontrol**.

```
tabpagenew = new TabPage();
Gc = (GridControl)Page.LoadControl(@"GridControl.ascx");
Gc.ID = "GC" + currDDIndex;
ASPxGridView grdPreview = (ASPxGridView)Gc.FindControl("ggc_preview");
grdPreview.ID = "grd" + currDDIndex;
tabpagenew.Controls.Add(Gc);
tabPreview.addTabPages(tabpagenew);
```

In **addTabPages** method, I just added Tab pages by its index,

```
public void addTabPages(TabPage tab_Page)
{
    ActiveIndex = ASPxPageControl1.ActiveTabIndex + 1;
    int index = ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Count + 1;
    ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Add(tab_Page);
    tab_Page.ToolTip = tab_Page.Text;
    tab_Page.Name = tab_Page.Name;                
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
    button.ImageUrl = "~\\Images\\close.png";
    button.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "Hand");
    button.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Close_Click);
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TabClose('" + hdnCurrentTab.ClientID + "','" + tab_Page.Index + "');");              
    tab_Page.TabTemplate = new AddTabHeading(button, tab_Page.Text, ASPxPopupMenu1,  ASPxPageControl1.ActiveTabPage.VisibleIndex, ASPxPageControl1);                
}
```

Comment: Can you post complete code or at least the part that adds Tab page?

Comment: @Filip : I just edited the description briefly with adding Tab page code.

Comment: Is addTabPages executed after button click or not?

Comment: @Filip : Yes, but the Tab control usercontrol gets refreshed after button click.

Answer (score 1):

In your aspx page:

1. You need to put the tab control between asp:UpdatePanel.
2. Add a button inside hidden DIV.
3. Whenever you need to add a new tab, call the button click function.

This is the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ClientDetailsUpdatePanel" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="display:none">
            <asp:Button ID="CallBackHiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="CallBackHiddenButton_Click" Text="Button"/>
        </div>

        <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="DetailsClientTabs" ClientInstanceName="DetailsClientTabs" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"
            ActiveTabStyle-Border-BorderStyle="None" EnableCallBacks="false" 
            ActiveTabStyle-BackColor="Transparent" ContentStyle-BackColor="Transparent"
            ContentStyle-BorderRight-BorderStyle="None" ContentStyle-BorderLeft-BorderStyle="None"
            ContentStyle-BorderTop-BorderStyle="None" ContentStyle-BorderBottom-BorderStyle="None"
            EnableTheming="False" ContentStyle-Border-BorderColor="Transparent">

        </dx:ASPxPageControl>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now in your C# code:

1- Handle the button click to add a new page:

```
protected void CallBackHiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage newPage = new TabPage("test" + DateTime.Now.Second, "maged" + DateTime.Now.Second);
        DetailsClientTabs.TabPages.Add(newPage);

        //You always need to reassign the previous tabs pages
        for (int i = 0; i < DetailsClientTabs.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            Control cc = Page.LoadControl("~/Forms/Client/Details/TabsPages/TestUserCtrl.ascx");
            cc.ID = String.Format("control_di_", DateTime.Now);
            DetailsClientTabs.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(cc);
        }

        //If you need to get the new added tab to be the active one!
    DetailsClientTabs.ActiveTabIndex = DetailsClientTabs.TabPages.Count - 1;
        }
```

This may help you.